# memcache in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am having an application developed in python and google app engine, but when i am try to customize this application then it is giving me compile time error in the previous code which is running fine on live. Code is:

```
if version in ['beta', 'alpha'] :
            type=version
            version = memcache.get(type)
            if not version:
                v = RouterVersions.get_by_key_name(type)
                if not v : 
                    logging.error('No version found in RouterModel for %s', type)
                    self.error(404)
                    return;

                version = v.version
                memcache.add(v.type, version)
```

whenver i am using memcache.add or get property it is giving compile time error "undefined variable from import get".
I am not able to know why is it so. I am new to python and google app engine. My application was created in python 2.5 and i am using 2.7 now. Is that the issue or something else ?

Comment: You should post the full stacktrace. Currently I don't see how your code should cause an "undefined variable from import get".

Comment: Also, please cross reference the line numbers in the stacktrace and the line numbers in your code snippet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you perhaps name a file memcache.py?  If so remove it and also memcache.pyc.

Comment: All hail StackOverflow, where you might get debugging advice from THE MAN WHO WROTE YOUR PROGRAMMING LANGUAGE.